# Bitbucket Pipelines .NET Core Test Output

Tags: .net, .net-core, xunit, bitbucket-pipelines

Has any one been able to get test results working with Bitbucket Pipelines.

Found a few articles on this, essentially the problem seems to be the inability of the `dotnet test` runner to output test results into XML format.

I'm able to get so far as to output a TRX file as per this answer, but [Bitbucket does not support this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/test-reporting-in-pipelines-939708543.html) (apparently Bamboo does).

Here's what I have

```
dotnet test -c Release -r test-results -xml test.xml /path/to/proj.csproj
```

Comment: I was able to use this solution in a similar question- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52679074/57311

Comment: Yes, can confirm that the selected answer to that question works fine.

Comment: I've used **trx2unit**  outlined in the [documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/test-reporting-in-pipelines/).

Answer (score 1):

We use

```
dotnet test --logger "junit;LogFilePath=./test-reports/results.xml"
```

as suggested [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-15836) for example. Works as expected.